# What IRC servers are available for Ubuntu

Tags: server, software-recommendation, irc

I want to setup an IRC server in my local network. I would like to know the IRC server options available for Ubuntu.
I heard that `irc-hybrid` is good.  Do you have any other suggestions.
The thing is that I want to use an IRC server which is generally used by most of the Ubuntu community(who uses IRC server).
I would also like to know the exact steps to configure it.

Answer (score 4):

This is answered thoroughly (including both server packages and installation instructions) here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/IrcServer

Comment: I had seen that wiki. Its quite outdated, last edit was way back in 2008. If you have done this, could you please post the exact steps that worked for you.

Comment: Not much has changed in the world of IRC since 2008. :)  It's been quite a while since I had to support an ircd, but I believe dancer-ird was the one I used; the setup steps at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Dancer-IRCD look pretty familiar - and that particular how-to was last updated Nov '11, so I'd say go from there and see how you fare.

Answer (score 3):

This really is a matter of personal taste; I prefer Unreal myself but they are all fairly obtuse (likely by design, to keep "noobs" from operating IRC servers) and take some doing to set up, although `ircd-hybrid` as mentioned is probably an easier one. However, for an IRC server I've been running for a few years now on Ubuntu, I have been using Unreal 3.2 because I was most familiar with using networks that run Unreal.

Another important thing to consider is services, if you are new to IRC server administration you might be surprised to find out that things such as nickserv are not part of the IRC package but services. Anope is the most common to use with Unreal but it works with other IRC servers.

Comment: Please share the exact steps for installing the IRC server on which you're experienced.

Comment: That would require writing basically an entire wiki to go over comprehensively. The short version is that you need to go through the configuration files in great detail, and this will take you some time, and vary greatly depending on your specific environment and requirements. IRC is not a modern "setup and go" thing, and there are no wizards. Installing and configuring an IRC server is a very manual, specific-to-the-situation process.

Comment: Some basic steps that are common to most situations, would be good.

Answer (score -1):

```
sudo apt-get install openssl libssl-dev

sudo apt-get install ircd-hybrid

sudo nano /etc/ircd-hybrid/ircd.conf

oqIj6e9yADr8c

sudo /etc/init.d/ircd-hybrid restart

/quote MODLOAD m_force.so

m_mkpasswd.so
m_opme.so
m_ojoin.so
m_roleplay.so
m_forcenick.so

http://www.installion.co.uk/ubuntu/saucy/universe/h/hybserv/en/install/index.html

deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu saucy main universe

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install hybserv

sudo nano /etc/hybserv/hybserv.conf

sudo /etc/init.d/hybserv restart
```

Comment: Why has the `sudo nano /etc/ircd-hybrid/ircd.conf` been run, and no edit been done to the file? What is `oqIj6e9yADr8c` for?

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu.com Please provide an explanation why these commands are used and what is their purpose.

Comment: @Petraeus, It doesn't matter if its lengthy, but it should be understandable on its own. So, it would be nice if you could expand  and make the answer more clear. Thank you.

Answer (score -4):

Basic steps:

1. Find package
2. Decompress/install make package
3. Run package
4. Connect to service

Comment: Hello, and welcome to askubuntu.com . For future reference, make your answer more clear, providing examples in addition to actual steps. How would user find package ? what commands or tools needed ? Be as clear as possible